# What Happens in the Parsha Parellel's Current Events

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, chasidut-hasidism

Where is the source(s) that say that what happens each week in the parsha parallels current world events? I believe it is found in chassidus, but I am not sure where.

Comment: Did different events happen in Israel when they read the Torah every three years instead of every year?

Comment: I guess current events was poor phrasing. What I meant is that there is an idea that the weekly parsha is always relevant to one's current life situation.

Comment: I heard the same idea, but with the daf yomi. See this video from min 5:54 ff https://youtu.be/d8pBv3PncOk?t=354

Comment: Is any parsha ever not relevant to your current life situation?